# How to access webserver from different computer on same network?

Tags: ip-address

Hi I have a webserver on my developer computer but I want to access website through a different computer on the same network. I tried typing IP address of the developer computer and giving the path but no luck.
Can someone suggest what is the quick and easy solution?

Comment: Are you using the default port 80 on your webserver?

Comment: Can you ping the development machine? Might be a firewall issue.

Comment: @shadowhorst i think so i m using default port 80 but how do i check and be sure?

Comment: @stuartmclark its "request timed out". How do i correct it?

Comment: If you access the website on your development machine are you using something like http://localhost or http://localhost:8888 for example?

Comment: @Darsh Go to your development machine and check which port your site is being hosted on you can do this by going to IIS and navigating to the site and checking the properties. If your port is set to 80 change it to 85 just to be sure.

Once you have this go to your firewall security center and create a new inbound rule on that port.

Comment: @shadowhorst yes I am using localhost/pos/v3/index.html on developer machine

Comment: @ stuartmclark i not using IIS using mysql and apache

Comment: So it looks like the default port 80. Then set a new inbound rule in your firewall for port 80 like stuartmclark said.

Comment: @shadowhorst i am really new at this do you have any link where i can learn how to set rules for firewalls?

Comment: What kind of operating system are you using?

Comment: @shadowhorst i m using windows vista

Comment: This one might help: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Open-a-port-in-Windows-Firewall - Use TCP Port 80 and your local network in scope.

Comment: @shadowhorst thanks for the help but its not working. I am confused..

Comment: So try disabling the firewall completly. If its working, you know it is a firewall issue. If not i am also confused ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very similar to the following post I've replied to some time ago:

[How do I connect to this localhost from another computer on the same network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682262/how-do-i-connect-to-this-localhost-from-another-computer-on-the-same-network/15431636?noredirect=1#comment27737853_15431636)